# AVAssetResourceLoader stop loading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I am implementing a custom `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` class to preview and cache my videos.

i.e

```
 AVURLAsset *asset ;
        assetLoader = [[AssetLoaderDelegate alloc] init];
        assetLoader.fileUrl = self.videoURL;
        asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self videoURL:self.videoURL WithCustomScheme:@"streaming"] options:nil];
        [asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:assetLoader queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Where the AssetLoaderDelegate is a custom class conforming to the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`protocol.

It works as expected. However the issue that I am facing is that occasionally I need to move on from the Video player to another view and hence stop the loader from loading data, but I didn't find anyway to stop it.
 `[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];` cant obviously handle it I guess.

How do I stop `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` loading data?